# How to render dynamically generated inline SVG by using custom directive in angular 6

Tags: javascript, html, angular, svg, angular2-directives

I'm having difficulty in rendering dynamically generated inline SVG in my application.

I have written a custom directive which generates inline SVG from a chemical reaction data.

**rxn-to-image.directive.ts**

```js
@Directive({
  selector: '[appRxnToImage]'
})
export class RxnToImageDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  set appRxnToImage(rxnString: any) {
    this.generateImageFromRxn(rxnString);
  }

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private el: ElementRef
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  private generateImageFromRxn(rxn) {
    // custom method that generated inline svg dynamicaaly 
    MarvinJSUtil.getPackage('#marvinjs-iframe').then(marvinNameSpace => {
      marvin = marvinNameSpace;
      const exporter = customMethodThatCreatesExporter;
      exporter.render(rxn).then(
        svg => {
          // once svg generated i will call applySvg method to render svg
          this.applySvg(svg);
        },
        error => {
          alert(error);
        }
      );
    });
  }
  private applySvg(svg) {
    this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = svg;
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
  }

}
```

SVG would like this:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="225" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" style="overflow: hidden; "><</svg>
```

calling directive from the template like this:

`<div *appRxnToImage="reactionString"></div>`

I want to render generated inline SVG inside the div.

doing like this to render SVG.

```
this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.innerHTML = svg;
this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
```

Anyone can please help me?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for this?

Comment: Sure @AnuradhaGunasekara

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara please find [stackblitzurl](https://stackblitz.com/github/venkatakrishna874/rxn-to-image?file=src%2Fapp%2Frxn-to-image.directive.ts) and [GitHubLink](https://github.com/venkatakrishna874/rxn-to-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reference to the fix: https://stackblitz.com/edit/g4j-structural-directive?file=src/main.ts

Basically after you create the embedded view, you can access the root nodes (in your example the div) and set the innerHTML their (line **37** of **rxn-to-image.directive.ts**)

Comment: Thankyou @g4j  It's helped me

Comment: can you help me to select SVG to change the styles i.e. width="100%" after loading